lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag Evented line 37209, line 37212, column 1
Пишу алгоритм отбора определённых событий журнала Windows и получаю ошибку что написал в заголовке.
<Evented>
<EventID Qualifiers="">23</EventID>
<Version>0</Version>
<Level>4</Level>
<Task>0</Task>
<Opcode>0</Opcode>
<Keywords>0x1000000000000000</Keywords>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2024-12-22 20:47:33.824215"></TimeCreated>
<EventRecordID>9766</EventRecordID>
<Correlation ActivityID="{61a55000-55e5-1017-0000-000000000000}" RelatedActivityID=""></Correlation>
<Execution ProcessID="1312" ThreadID="12052"></Execution>
<Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational</Channel>
<Computer>PDD</Computer>
<Security UserID="S-1-5-18"></Security>
<UserData><EventXML xmlns="Event_NS"><User>PDD\User</User>
<SessionID>1</SessionID>
</EventXML>
</UserData>
</Evented>

то место на которое ругается обработка
собственно сам код отбора, версия python 3.10
from Evtx.Evtx import Evtx
import lxml.etree as Et
tree = Et.parse('C:/Users/User/Desktop/EVTXTest.txt')
elements = tree.xpath('//EventID [contains(text(), "21")]')
for element in elements:
    print(element.text)

и сам traceback ошибки
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\URVUsers\main.py", line 42, in <module>
    Evtx_from_txt('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Test.evtx','C:/Users/User/Desktop/EVTXTest.txt')
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\URVUsers\main.py", line 41, in Evtx_from_txt
    SearchXML()
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\URVUsers\main.py", line 10, in SearchXML
    tree = Et.parse('C:/Users/User/Desktop/EVTXTest.txt')
  File "src\\lxml\\etree.pyx", line 3589, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 1958, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 1984, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 1887, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 1200, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 633, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 743, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\\lxml\\parser.pxi", line 672, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/EVTXTest.txt", line 37212
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag Evented line 37209, line 37212, column 1

Process finished with exit code 1


Выглядит нормально. Если только сам файл выкладывать и смотреть. Если там нет ничего конфиденциального. А, и добавьте импорты в код. Et - это что, etree? Ну и можно ещё версию питона добавить в вопрос.

Плюс вам за следование всем советам по оформлению вопроса )  Ну я не знаю, этот фрагмент нормально считывается, если отдельно. Возможно, ошибка "наведённая" из-за какого-то другого куска XML. Ну или я не знаю.

А зачем сохранять файл событий в XML, а потом читать, вроде есть библиотеки, которые evtx читают (хотя я сам их не пробовал).  Приведенный кусок XML нормальный, хотя бы напишите, какая строчка в нем соответствует строке 37212 из "большого" файла. Еще можно открыть файл каким-нибудь редактором XML, там часто подсвечиваются ошибочные места.
